# Gatling Configuration

Tags: scala, configuration, gatling

Is it possible to programmatically set the gatling.core.directory.data path from the gatling.conf?

I am attempting to read in a CSV that is not the in the default directory.

I have attempted to do;

```
System.getProperties.setProperty("gatling.core.directory.data",FilePathHelper.getGatlingDataFilePath.getAbsolutePath)
```

But I still get a null pointer for my file;

```
val users = csv("user.csv")
```

Thanks

Comment: You could specify your data folder by calling gatling with the `-df` flag. See the docs [here](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration/#command-line-options)

Comment: Thanks, but I am building a propriety plugin that encapsulates gatling so that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end changing the data path is very easy and to run from code is just as simple!

```
val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder
props.simulationClass(<your runner>)
props.dataDirectory(new File(<your data dir>))
props.resultsDirectory(new File(<your report dir>))
```

Gatling.fromMap(props.build)